Levi-Civita connection $\tilde{\nabla}_\tilde{X}V = i \tilde{\nabla} X$ with $\pi: (S^{2n+1}, \tilde{g}) \to (\mathbb{C}P^n,g)$ canonical one
I am making the following exercise about submersions in Riemannian Geometry. Exercise Riemannian geometry
I managed to solve the exercise itself, but I do not see why $\tilde{\nabla}_\tilde{X}V = i \tilde{X}$ (this is in the question: "Apply the previous exercise, using that for $\pi: S^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{C}P^n$, the vertical space is spanned by the vector field $\xi(q) = iq, q \in S^{2n+1}$, and therefore $\tilde{\nabla}_\tilde{X}V = i \tilde{X}$).

Could you share the source, please?
